# Are members of a nested class be members of the enclosing class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the example that follows [temp.dep.type] p3

```cpp
template<class T> struct A {
  typedef int M;
  struct B {
    typedef void M;
    struct C;
  };
};

template<class T> struct A<T>::B::C : A<T> {
  M m;                          // OK, A<T>​::​M
};
```

The example implies that A is a current instantiation class in the definition of A::B::C. However, according to [temp.dep.type#1.2]

> A name or template-id refers to the current instantiation if it is
>
> > - [...]
> > - in the definition of a primary class template or **a member of a primary class template**, the name of the class template followed by the template argument list of its template-head ([temp.arg]) enclosed in <> (or an equivalent template alias specialization),
> > - [...]

In this example, the primary class template is `A`, Is that saying the member class `C` of the nested class `B` is a member of class template `A`?

Comment: Your quote is basically for injected class name, that you don't use (`A::M` would use injected class name). unclear for me the question. A doesn't have `int m;`; `C::M` can only be `A::M` (via inheritance). `B::M` is just confusing.

Comment: @Jarod42 The quote I cited is exactly about *template-id* which may name a current instantiation.